# Как сгенерировать список [3**0, 3**1, 3**1 + 3**0] в Python

Tags: python, list

Есть ли способ сгенерировать такой список с помощью одного цикла?

Comment: Непонятно зачем тут цикл

Comment: Можно более подробнее о том, какой именно список нужен?

Comment: надо чтобы на выходе список был вида [1, 3, 4]

Comment: то есть имеем число n и из него сгенерировать [n^0, n^1, n^1 + n^0]

Answer (score 1):

Цикл тут и не нужен, просто делаете этот список одной строчкой:

```
a = [1, n, n + 1] #возведение в степень тут вообще не нужно
```

Answer (score 1):

В чём проблема просто поставить переменную, которая будет принимать число в список?

```
n = 3

result = [n**0, n**1, n**1 + n**0]

print(result)

Результат:
[1, 3, 4]
```

Если для многократного использования, то можно через функцию:

```
def this(n):
    result = [n ** 0, n ** 1, n ** 1 + n ** 0]
    return result

print(this(3))

Результат:
[1, 3, 4]
```